# Will elementary OS install fine on the HP Elite X2 1012 G2 tablet?

Tags: system-installation

Just wondering if elementary OS will install just fine and work with the keyboard and touchpad. Touchscreen support and active stylus support is of course a bonus but not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your question sparked an interest I had with one of these machines about 3 or 4 months ago as I was seriously thinking of buying one. I did a little research back then and found a couple things in regards to a Linux install.

From what I can remember reading, there were issues getting both cameras (front & back) working with the back camera causing the issue. Also, if you are going to dual boot with Windows, you are going to want to disable the Fast Boot option as that can cause some issues while trying to install.

Lastly, in almost all cases, if you are able to boot the machine into a live session via a USB stick and the desktop loads and works then an install should work out just fine. But, remember I said almost! The one advantage is that Ubuntu (the OS on which eOS is based) works directly with HP which helps make the OS/machine compatibility quite good.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Sounds good. Still would like to wait for a confirmation though - this will likely be my only computer and if I can't get eOS or some variant of Linux to install, I'm pretty much sunk.

Comment: Smart approach for sure! The real issue tends to be kernel development in my opinion as it kind of lags behind the newest hardware releases. I'll keep an eye out with regards to your machine and update this post if I find anything related.